# Nhibernate error 'Invalid column name' when column does exist

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Hi I have an object called document and one called user

Document

```
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Documentmap

```
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        References(x => x.User);
    }
```

User

```
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    private readonly IList<Document> _documents = new List<Document>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get { return _documents; } }
    public virtual void Remove(Document document)
    {
        _documents.Remove(document);
    }
    public virtual void Add(Document document)
    {
        if (!document.IsNew() && _documents.Contains(document)) return;
        _documents.Add(document);
    }

    Map(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.MiddleInitial);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        HasMany(x => x.Documents).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

Pretty straighforward ( they inherit from base class with stuff like createddate modifieddate etc )

when I try to get all doc by userid I get this

Invalid column name 'UserId'.

the column most definitely is in the table.  It also lists several of the base class items as not being there.

I take the sql and past it in query manager and I get intellisense saying they are invalid columns. I run it and it executes just fine.  Further more there are plenty of other objects using these base classes with no problems.

I have tried various things like explicitly mapping the key name, the column name using inverse etc to no avail.  Don't really know what to do.
Thanks,
Raif

//EDIT as per request  sorry it's so verbose.  the database is created by nhibernate create schema

Document

```
public class Document : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentCategory DocumentCategory { get; set; }
    [ValueOf(typeof(DocumentFileType))]
    public virtual string FileType { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Pages { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? Size { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentMap : EntityMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.FileUrl);
        Map(x => x.Pages);
        Map(x => x.Size);
        Map(x => x.FileType);
        References(x => x.DocumentCategory);
        References(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

Entity

```
public class Entity : IGridEnabledClass, IEquatable<Entity>
{
    public virtual int EntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int ChangedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Archived { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsNew()
    {
        return EntityId == 0;
    }
```

User

```
 public class User : DomainEntity, IUser
{
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNonEmpty]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    [ValidateNonEmpty]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string StartPage { get; set; }
    public virtual UserLoginInfo UserLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Photo HeadShot { get; set; }
    private readonly IList<Document> _documents = new List<Document>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get { return _documents; } }
    public virtual void Remove(Document document)
    {
        _documents.Remove(document);
    }
    public virtual void Add(Document document)
    {
        if (!document.IsNew() && _documents.Contains(document)) return;
        _documents.Add(document);
    }
    several more collections

public class UserMap : DomainEntityMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.MiddleInitial);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.BirthDate);
        Map(x => x.StartPage);
        References(x => x.UserStatus);
        References(x => x.UserLoginInfo);
        References(x => x.HeadShot);
        HasMany(x => x.Documents).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

database tables create from script select to menu item on management studio

```
  SELECT [EntityId]
  ,[CreateDate]
  ,[ChangeDate]
  ,[ChangedBy]
  ,[Archived]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Description]
  ,[FileUrl]
  ,[Pages]
  ,[Size]
  ,[FileType]
  ,[DocumentCategoryId]
  ,[UserId]
  FROM [DecisionCriticalSuite].[dbo].[Document]
 GO


  SELECT [EntityId]
  ,[CreateDate]
  ,[ChangeDate]
  ,[ChangedBy]
  ,[Archived]
  ,[TenantId]
  ,[OrgId]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[MiddleInitial]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[BirthDate]
  ,[StartPage]
  ,[UserStatusId]
  ,[UserLoginInfoId]
  ,[HeadShotId]
  ,[OrganizationId]
  FROM [DecisionCriticalSuite].[dbo].[User]
  GO
```

error from nhprof

```
ERROR: 
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'EntityId'.
Invalid column name 'EntityId'.
Invalid column name 'CreateDate'.
Invalid column name 'ChangeDate'.
Invalid column name 'ChangedBy'.
Invalid column name 'Archived'.
Invalid column name 'FileType'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.Could not execute query: SELECT documents0_.UserId as UserId1_, documents0_.EntityId as EntityId1_, documents0_.EntityId as EntityId49_0_, documents0_.CreateDate as CreateDate49_0_, documents0_.ChangeDate as ChangeDate49_0_, documents0_.ChangedBy as ChangedBy49_0_, documents0_.Archived as Archived49_0_, documents0_.Name as Name49_0_, documents0_.Description as Descript7_49_0_, documents0_.FileUrl as FileUrl49_0_, documents0_.Pages as Pages49_0_, documents0_.Size as Size49_0_, documents0_.FileType as FileType49_0_, documents0_.DocumentCategoryId as Documen12_49_0_, documents0_.UserId as UserId49_0_ FROM [Document] documents0_ WHERE           documents0_.UserId=@p0
```

Comment: Is there a UserId column in DocumentMap?  Maybe you should post the way your database tables look and the query NHibernate is generating.

Comment: I can post all that stuff it's going to be very verbose cuz I cut out a lot.  Hopefully this wont be to obnoxious

Comment: Only show the relevant columns in your database tables. Also you didn't answer my first question.

Comment: there is a userId in the document table, and the documentmap reverences(x=>x.user) which creates a userId foreignkey.  I have a convention for naming my key columns ObjectId rather then Object_ID

Comment: Are you sure it's running that query against the same database you are running against in sql management studio?

Comment: omg somebody checked in a different web.config. what a colossal pain in the rear. is there some way to erase this from the web?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure nhibernate is querying against the same database as what you are querying against in sql management studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue because I had mapped *Entity1.Entity2* as Entity3.

So when joining, it would attempt to use a property from Entity3 as if it existed on Entity2.